# Calculating BMI using SAS logic

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like the following for many patients

```
Patient   VisitDate   Value   Unit   Type 
 A        Jan12019     1      m      Height
 A        Jan12019     50     kg     Weight
 A        Jan52019     2      m      Height
 A        Jan52019     55     kg     Weight
```

I am trying to add BMI to get the following dataset for those patients:

```
Patient   VisitDate   Value      Unit   Type 
 A        Jan12019     1         m      Height
 A        Jan12019     50        kg     Weight
 A        Jan52019     2         m      Height
 A        Jan52019     55        kg     Weight
 A        Jan52019     50/1^2    kg/m2  BMI
 A        Jan52019     55/2^2    kg/m2  BMI
```

I am not too concerned about the actual code but I am trying to understand the logic beyond programming this in SAS. Below is what I have so far in psuedo code:

Create BMI data set. For each patient on each visit date, value = weight/height^2. Type = BMI. Unit = kg/m2. Keep Patient, VisitDate info.

Comment: Please include any attempts in your questions, specifically any code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the logic, you are trying to get the BMI calculated from two rows of a patient with weight and Height on same date.

So one way is to use proc sql, where you can join the main table with itself on the basis of same patient name and visitdate ..

Secondly, you can also separate the main dataset into two based on "Type" or "Unit" and then do merge .. it is upto you which logic you want to implement. My approach looks like this:

```
 proc sql;
  create table BMI
  as
  select a.Patient, 
        a.VisitDate,
        b.value/(a.value*a.value) as value,
        "kg/m2" as Unit,
        "BMI" as Type
   from have a
   inner join have b
          on a.patient=b.Patient
          and a.visitdate=b.visitdate
          and a.Type="Height"
          and b.Type="Weight";
  quit;
```

Comment: Hi! I was wondering, if in the original dataset you had an additional type where c.Type = "Circumference" would you use the same approach and just join the third dataset?

Comment: you can have as many joins as you need provided it doesn't overcomplicate the query, so if there is another type "Circumference"- yes we can code it using type variable in another join.. but the concept should be clear